# How unnesting array works in BigQuery

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

Let's take the following query:

```
with main as (
    select "David" as name, ["Joan", "Rick"] as parents union all
    select "Kyle" as name, ["Cathy", "Rick"] as parents
)
select
    name, parent
from
    main 
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(parents) as parent
```

[image]

My question is why the `<table> CROSS JOIN UNNEST(field)` only joins with the 'table-from-array' within that row, and not in the entire table. For example, why doesn't the query do this instead:

```
main
    `name`
    - David
    - Kyle

<derived_from_array>
   `parent`
    - Rick
    - Joan
    - Cathy
    - Rick
```

Or, put another way, why doesn't the end-query do this:

```
with main as (
    select "David" as name union all
    select "Kyle" as name
),
derived_from_array as (
    select "Rick" as parent union all
    select "Joan" as parent union all
    select "Cathy" as parent union all
    select "Rick" as parent
)
select
    name, parent
from
    main 
    CROSS JOIN derived_from_array
```

[image]

In other words, how does it know to build the table-from-array **only within that row** ?

Comment: that is the whole beauty of joining with unnest - it joins with the row that unnested array is from! this is a by design!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cross join unnest()` is implementing a *lateral join*.  Unfortunately, BigQuery does not make this explicit.  However, if you add aliases, I think it becomes clearer:

```
select m.name, parent
from main m cross join
     unnest(m.parents) as parent;
```

So, for each row in `main`, the `cross join` is joining together a set.  What set?  The set that is generated by unnesting `parents` *in that row*.  Hence, the data from different rows is not mixed together.

Using more standard syntax, this lateral keyword would make this more obvious:

```
select m.name, parent
from main m cross join lateral
     unnest(m.parents) as parent;
```

But as I say, BigQuery does not support this Standard SQL syntax.

Comment: thanks, here's a good reference too for the `LATERAL`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/651174.

Answer (score 0):

to make it even more friendly and better understood - you can use below version

```
with main as (
    select "David" as name, ["Joan", "Rick"] as parents union all
    select "Kyle" as name, ["Cathy", "Rick"] as parents
)
select
    name, parent
from
    main m
    CROSS JOIN m.parents as parent
```

As you can see parents array is treated here as a table within the respective row, so you join each of the rows in this sub-table with the respective row of parent table